# Chess Puzzle to calculate the minimum number of movements of pawn

Tags: chess, probability

Given an N×N chessboard, with two pieces, a black pawn and a white pawn randomly placed on the chessboard. What is the minimum number of steps required by the white pawn to reach the black pawn under the following assumptions?

1. The pawns are always inside the board.
2. The white pawn can move in either of the 8 directions.
3. The black pawn is always stationary.
4. The white pawn can move only 1 step at a time.

Comment: Shouldn't the minimum always be 1, assuming the RNG cooperates?

Comment: I am not sure...is this question related to probability?

Comment: Well, asking for the minimum in the context of this question doesnt make all that sense. If you mean the minimum across all of the possibilities, it's definitely 1. If you mean something else, I'm not sure if we have enough information.

Comment: Hi @susane and welcome to Puzzling. Unfortrunately, we're a bit strict around here about what actually counts as a _puzzle_ and this question doesn't really fit. Also, it sounds as if this is a question you got from somewhere else, and for those we require proper attribution -- we need to know where it's from, so that the source gets appropriate credit. So I've closed this as off-topic. I'm sorry if this is a discouraging introduction to Puzzling; if you're interested in puzzles, I hope you'll stay around anyway!

Answer (score 1):

> If we number both rows and columns, then the minimum number of moves is MAX(ABS(WHITE.Row - BLACK.Row),ABS(WHITE.Column - BLACK.Column)), for any random placements of the two pawns. (In other words, the minimum number of moves is the GREATER of the difference in row number and the difference in column number .)

Comment: I think that is a correct answer. Thank you very much.